# Open Route Service - LRM

Tags: leaflet, leaflet-routing-machine

ive been struggeling for awhile with this,
so i got two questions to ask.

First question:i cant change the profile on open route service.
my code is working when i put in the api-key in the code below.

```
var control;

function tests() {
    var control = L.Routing.control({
        waypoints: [ 
        L.latLng(coords),
        L.latLng(coords2)
        ],
    router: new L.Routing.openrouteservice('Api-Key'),
}).addTo(map);
document.getElementById("RouteButton").onclick = tests;
};
```

But when i try changing the profile, it either doesnt change or get error messages.

The things i tried so far is.

```
  router: new L.Routing.openrouteservice({api_key:'HIDDEN', profile:'footwalking'),
```

and

```
 router: new L.Routing.openrouteservice('https:// api.openrouteservice.org /directions? & api_key = Hidden& profile = foot-walking'),
```

The first one works, but the profile doesnt change It is still using the driving-car default profile.

The Second one gives me a two error messages,

First error message is | Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?' from origin 'http://localhost:8000' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. |

Second error message | corslite.js:87 GET https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions? 403 (Forbidden) |

both of the error messages gives off a long url which ive shorted down to https://api.openrouteservice.org/directions?.

The other Question i got is, how do i clear the map, so a previously drawn route gets removed when a new route is drawn. On the picture below you can see what happens at the moment when i request a second route, both the old and the new i shown.

[two routes on the same map](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XmafB.jpg)

Hope you guys can help.

Comment: did you found a working solution? I have the same problem

Answer (score -2):

open the L.Routing.OpenRouteService.js